# Made a socket in winsock and it ask for the ip and then port you want to connect to, but doesn't allow you to put in the port

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I made a simple socket using winsock in C++ and instead of hard coding it I wanted to be able to change it by inserting variables so it ask what ip and port you want to connect to but after you type in the ip it says "What PORT do you want to use" but then goes to the next conditional and says "Unable to connect to server: 0".

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main() {
    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    char name[500] = "";
    char ipADDRESS[500] = "";
    char sPORT[500] = "";

    sockaddr_in sName;
    int sNameSize =  sizeof(sName);

    char *sendbuf = "Test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    int WSAERROR = WSAGetLastError();

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.

    printf("What IP ADDRESS do you want to connect to? \n");
    cin.get(ipADDRESS, sizeof(ipADDRESS));
    printf("What PORT do you want to use? \n");
    //cin.get(sPORT, sizeof(sPORT));
    fgets(sPORT, sizeof(sPORT), stdin);
    //u_short PORT;
    u_short PORT = strtoul(sPORT, NULL, 0);
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipADDRESS);                            //74.125.196.191
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        printf("Unable to connect to server: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    //Get local host name
    iResult = gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Host Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Could not resolve host name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    //------------------------
    //Get peer name
    iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Peer Name: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sName.sin_addr));
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Could not get peer name: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());



    //-------------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);

    //-----------------------------
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult); //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("From server: %s\n", recvbuf);
        }
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else if (WSAERROR == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            printf("recv failed: WSAETIMEDOUT\n");

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for [`std::fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) and you'll find it is ceasing its read upon encountering the line end you failed to exorcise after reading your ip address. Why you're not using the formatted input facilities of the C++ standard library for this is the real question. A single-step through a debugger and examination of `sPORT` would be pretty telling as well.

Comment: I was using `cin.get()` because it would get multiple words instead of stopping after a space like `cin` but thanks to you I just realized I don't need it. Problem solved. Thank you! :)

Comment: You can use `std::getline(std::cin, s)` where `s` is a `std::string`, then `std::cin >> port`, where `port` is `u_short`. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you very much that will definitely come in handy. :)